# Struts 2: excluding method from validation from just the defaultStack interceptor

Tags: struts2, interceptor, interceptorstack

I want to be able to disable form validation for one action in Struts 2, but have the rest of the interceptor stack still be able to run.

I have an interceptor that checks to see if the user is logged in, which I always want execute, but for some actions (inputting information, for instance), I don't want the action's `validate` to be called.

I tried doing something like the following:

```
<interceptors>

    <interceptor name="bankingAuthenticator"
        class="csc309.a4.banking.BankUserAuthenticator"/>

    <interceptor-stack name="secureBanking">
        <interceptor-ref name="bankingAuthenticator"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    </interceptor-stack>

</interceptors>

<default-interceptor-ref name="secureBanking"/>

<action name="Deposit!*" method="{1}" class="csc309.a4.banking.Deposit">
    <result name="success">/banking/Deposit.jsp</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
        <param name="workflow.excludeMethods">choose</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
</action>
```

But it skips out on both the `bankingAuthenticator` interceptor as well as the validation.

Comment: Correct; if you specify an `interceptor-ref` for a single action, you must specify *all* the interceptors for that action! You should add your solution as an answer then accept it so future visitors can benefit from your work :)

Comment: what is the difference in the code you have written above and the one you have written in the answer... Can you tell me I didnt get it properly.....

Comment: @NIVESHSENGAR, the difference is that the interceptor name in the Deposit action is "defaultStack" in the above code and "secureBanking" in the one in the answer.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is choose here? Is the method inside where? I tried like below. But it still not excluding  `<action name="login">
     <interceptor-ref name="secureStack">
         <param name="workflow.excludeMethods">*</param>
     </interceptor-ref>
  <result>login.jsp</result>
  </action>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out--the solution looks like this:

```
<action name="Deposit!*" method="{1}" class="csc309.a4.banking.Deposit">
    <result name="success">/banking/Deposit.jsp</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="secureBanking">
        <param name="workflow.excludeMethods">choose</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
</action>
```

Interceptor parameters can be restricted to specific interceptors by prepending the interceptor name to the parameter name. In this case, only the `workflow` interceptor will exclude the `choose` method; other interceptors will still fire for the `choose` action method.

Comment: Awesome; glad you figured it out.